# How could an object running a thread communicate back to the containing class?

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, javafx, thread-safety

```
Class Person()
{
Eyes eyes;

Person(){
eyes = new Eyes();
eyes.watching();
}

Thread updateGUI(){
//want to safely  report what's being seen
}

}


Class Eyes()
{
String whatIsee;

public void watching()
{
    Task task = new Task()
    {
        while(1)
        {
        whatIsee = look();
        //then send what I see back to Person
        }
    }
}
}
```

Could I pass a list of "whatIHaveSeen" into the Eyes constructor. An do it that way. I'm aware work will be needed to make it thread safe. I just want and understanding of how to go about doing it.

Comment: What language is this? Doesn't seem to be java...

Comment: If you're looking for something like SwingUtilities.invokeLater... then the answer to your question is Platform.runLater(runnable); (_"Run the specified Runnable on the JavaFX Application Thread at some unspecified time in the future."_) However I assume this is not the answer you're looking for, because this was asked (and answered) like a gazillion times before.     I was assuming this based on the tags of your question.